# Autosave option in a modal dialog with Save & Cancel buttons

Tags: cancel, modal, autosave

Scenario - A modal dialog where a user can type in anything (basically, Notes) with Save & Cancel buttons present, and Auto Save implemented. Auto Save has a purpose - it will avoid the messy situation of the user who might lose out a really long written text.

Now, what if the user types in something > it gets auto saved > user hits the Cancel button.

What would be the potential outcome and expected results out of this?

Answer (score 2):

In short

For a new entry: All input should be dismissed and the auto save deleted

For when editing an existing entry: The new input should be saved to a separate file. If the user hits **OK** then overwrite the old file with the new. If the user hits **Cancel** the new file should be deleted and the value of the entry should load the value of the old file.

Eg. 
Existing entry: "I like bananas."
Hit **Edit** -> open modal, begin typing after existing text "because they are bent".
IF hit **OK** -> Entry: "I like bananas. because they are bent".
OR if hit
**Cancel** -> Entry: "I like bananas."

Answer (score 0):

While I can see it working without adding a step to the process, I would go the extra mile and:

**Ask the user.**

A simple popup saying "Commit changes?" with [yes] and [no] will do, or perhaps allow answers like [yes], [no] and a [cancel] for when it was pressed accidentally.

Ideally, offer the option to save whatever answer they gave and use that next time as well, to make their future experience water-tight as well.